# is the number of colums limited for an Entity?

Tags: google-app-engine

I might have an Entity with possibly thousands of columns, and was wondering if it would pose any problem (nothing will be indexed):

- Will queries be slower if the number of columns increases?
- Can there be in theory an unlimited number of columns?

Comment: There are a number of other things to take into consideration, such as  having that number of auto indexes for each of the properties.  Writes will be expensive as you may have 1000 indexes being updated.  Do you really need 1000's of properties (remember they aren't columns) or do you need many named properties (which could be embedded within a structured property.   You entity size is limited to 1MB , this includes the names of the properties as well as their values.  Also will you need all properties for every entity or would an expando style entity work ?

Comment: well the idea was to have a sort of map<Day,int> to count some stuff for every day. The problem is that using objectify as a wrapper to app engine, it will create a new column potentially every day. Also what are auto indexes ? I am not familiar with that and would like to know more

Comment: Oh you use java, so I can't help with specifics.  In python you mark each property with noindex=True then there will be an index created for the property unless it is TextProperty or BlobProperty.  Do you need to query/filter/sort by these properties ?  If not why not store the properties in a blob.

Answer (score 0):

While I never had thousands of columns to know about the speed and performance, as it looks from the data viewer on the dashboard the number of columns should be unlimited:

[image: number of columns]

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the GAE Datastore is essentially a very large key-value store right down to property level, in principle an unlimited number of properties are allowed.  Just not all together in one record for space reasons, as others already said.

Datastore is schemaless, but many libraries such as JDO, JPA and Objectify aim to "fix" this "deficiency" by introducing some schema of their own.  That is unhelpful in your scenario.

I suggest you bypass those libraries and directly call the Datastore low-level API as per [this example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) instead.  You can avoid the overheads of indexing if you change the setProperty calls to setUnindexedProperty as often as possible.  Remember to test for a null return from a getProperty call for a property that may be absent in some records.